# How to implement a custom identity model for JBoss Portal?

Tags: java, api, jboss, customization, jboss-portal

I want to implement a custom identity model in order to connect to a proprietary webservice providing user information.
So I followed the instructions on http://docs.jboss.com/jbportal/v2.7.1/referenceGuide/html/identity.html.

I am using JBoss Portal 2.7.2 with JBoss AS 4.2.3; java version 1.6.0_29

Here are the steps that I've done:

Creating a new maven project, pom.xml snippet:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.portal.identity</groupId>
    <artifactId>identity-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Implementation of the User interface:

```
package com.mycompany.myIdentity;

import org.jboss.portal.identity.IdentityException;
import org.jboss.portal.identity.User;

public class MyUserImpl implements User {
...
}
```

Packaged to a jar file and deployed (= copied) to 
\jboss-portal-2.7.2\server\default\deploy\jboss-portal.sar\lib.

Changes in \jboss-portal-2.7.2\server\default\deploy\jboss-portal.sar\conf\identity\identity-config.xml, 
replacing the existing User-type module with the new one (it doesn't need any config):

```
<module>
    <type>User</type>

    <service-name>portal:service=Module,type=User</service-name>
    <class>com.mycompany.myIdentity.MyUserImpl</class>

    <config/>
</module>
```

After starting the server by double-clicking the run.bat und browsing the site http://localhost:8080/portal
I get the following exception:

> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction
>       org.jboss.portal.server.servlet.PortalServlet.service(PortalServlet.java:278)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>       org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>
> root cause
>
> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction
>   org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext.currentSession(JTASessionContext.java:61)
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:544)
>   org.jboss.portal.core.impl.model.portal.PersistentPortalObjectContainer.getObjectNode(PersistentPortalObjectContainer.java:252)
>   org.jboss.portal.core.impl.model.portal.AbstractPortalObjectContainer.getContext(AbstractPortalObjectContainer.java:112)
>   org.jboss.portal.core.impl.model.portal.AbstractPortalObjectContainer.getContext(AbstractPortalObjectContainer.java:81)
>   org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.DefaultPortalCommandFactory.doMapping(DefaultPortalCommandFactory.java:72)
>   org.jboss.portal.core.controller.Controller.handle(Controller.java:252)
>   org.jboss.portal.server.RequestControllerDispatcher.invoke(RequestControllerDispatcher.java:51)
>   org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:131)
>   org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:157)
>   org.jboss.portal.server.servlet.PortalServlet.service(PortalServlet.java:252)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

I get the same exception even without deploying the jar file, just by changing the identity-config.xml file. So I assume
that my jar isn't loaded at all. Furthermore my new module has nothing to do with databases and thus needs no JTA transaction.

So what am I missing to get this thing working?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE 1:**

Hello again!

I was able to make a little progress by carefully examining the server log files. The server could not parse
the xml file identity-config.xml, so after some experimenting I could make it parse this new file:

```
<identity-configuration>
    <datasources/>
    <modules>
        <module>
            <type>User</type>
            <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>
            <config/>
        </module>
        <module>
            <type>Role</type>
            <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>
            <config/>
        </module>
        <module>
            <type>Membership</type>
            <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>
            <config/>
        </module>
        <module>
            <type>UserProfile</type>
            <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>
            <config/>
        </module>
    </modules
    <options/>
</identity-configuration>
```

I had to add the following code to the \jboss-portal-2.7.2\server\default\deploy\jboss-portal.sar\conf\identity\standardidentity-config.xml

```
<module>
    <type>User</type>
    <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>

    <service-name>portal:service=Module,type=User</service-name>
    <class>com.myCompany.MyUser</class>

    <config />
</module>
<module>
    <type>Role</type>
    <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>

    <service-name>portal:service=Module,type=Role</service-name>
    <class>com.myCompany.MyRole</class>

    <config />
</module>
<module>
    <type>Membership</type>
    <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>
    <service-name>portal:service=Module,type=Membership</service-name>
    <class>com.myCompany.MyMembership</class>
    <config />
</module>
<module>
    <type>UserProfile</type>
    <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>
    <service-name>portal:service=Module,type=UserProfile</service-name>
    <class>com.myCompany.MyUserProfile</class>
    <config />
</module>
```

As you can see I also implemented Role, Membership and UserProfile.
After that, the server complained about some missing properties it needed in those classes. So I added the following
to each of those four classes:

```
IdentityContext identityContext;
ServiceJNDIBinder jndiBinder;
String moduleType;

public String getModuleType() {
    return moduleType;
}

public void setModuleType(String moduleType) {
    this.moduleType = moduleType;
}

public ServiceJNDIBinder getJndiBinder() {
    return jndiBinder;
}

public void setJndiBinder(ServiceJNDIBinder jndiBinder) {
    this.jndiBinder = jndiBinder;
}

public IdentityContext getIdentityContext() {
    return identityContext;
}

public void setIdentityContext(IdentityContext identityContext) {
    this.identityContext = identityContext;
}
```

Unfortunately the server is still not content with this. I now find the following exception in my server log and
I have no idea how to solve this:

> 2011-11-21 08:55:54,696 ERROR [org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.container.LifeCycle] Cannot start
>   object
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.container.PortletInitializationException: The
>   portlet CMSAdminPortlet threw a portlet exception during init at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.jsr168.PortletContainerImpl.start(PortletContainerImpl.java:284)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.container.PortletContainerLifeCycle.invokeStart(PortletContainerLifeCycle.java:76)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.container.LifeCycle.managedStart(LifeCycle.java:92)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.container.PortletFilterLifeCycle.startDependents(PortletFilterLifeCycle.java:74)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.container.LifeCycle.managedStart(LifeCycle.java:128)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.container.PortletApplicationLifeCycle.startDependents(PortletApplicationLifeCycle.java:339)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.container.LifeCycle.managedStart(LifeCycle.java:128)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.deployment.jboss.PortletAppDeployment.start(PortletAppDeployment.java:226)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.core.deployment.jboss.PortletAppDeployment.start(PortletAppDeployment.java:94)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.server.deployment.jboss.DeploymentContext.start(DeploymentContext.java:99)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.server.deployment.jboss.PortalDeploymentInfoContext.add(PortalDeploymentInfoContext.java:86)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.server.deployment.jboss.ServerDeployer.registerFactory(ServerDeployer.java:134)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.server.deployment.jboss.AbstractDeploymentFactory.registerFactory(AbstractDeploymentFactory.java:113)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.server.deployment.jboss.AbstractDeploymentFactory.start(AbstractDeploymentFactory.java:152)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.deployment.jboss.PortletAppDeploymentFactory.start(PortletAppDeploymentFactory.java:147)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.jboss.portal.jems.as.system.JBossServiceModelMBean$ServiceMixin.execute(JBossServiceModelMBean.java:486)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.jems.as.system.JBossServiceModelMBean$ServiceMixin.startService(JBossServiceModelMBean.java:452)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.start(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:196)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.jems.as.system.JBossServiceModelMBean$6.invoke(JBossServiceModelMBean.java:374)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:995)
>   at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source) at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94) at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86) at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210) at
>   $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210) at
>   $Proxy199.start(Unknown Source) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.XSLSubDeployer.start(XSLSubDeployer.java:197) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782) at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210) at
>   $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
>   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
>   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
>   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94) at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86) at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
>   at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source) at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94) at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86) at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210) at
>   $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782) at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210) at
>   $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source) at
>   org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482) at
>   org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362) at
>   org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200) at
>   org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   javax.portlet.PortletException: Authorization Service not found at
>   org.jboss.portal.core.cms.ui.admin.CMSAdminPortlet.init(CMSAdminPortlet.java:140)
>   at org.jboss.portlet.JBossPortlet.init(JBossPortlet.java:387) at
>   org.jboss.portal.core.cms.ui.admin.CMSAdminPortlet.init(CMSAdminPortlet.java:151)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.jsr168.PortletContainerImpl.initPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:417)
>   at
>   org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.jsr168.PortletContainerImpl.start(PortletContainerImpl.java:256)
>   ... 134 more

and

> 2011-11-21 08:55:54,977 ERROR [org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete
>   Deployment listing:
>
> --- MBeans waiting for other MBeans --- ObjectName: portal:service=Module,type=IdentityServiceController State: FAILED
>   Reason: org.jboss.portal.identity.IdentityException: Cannot initiate
>   identity modules:  I Depend On: portal:service=Hibernate
>   portal:service=IdentityEventManager Depends On Me:
>   portal:service=AuthorizationProvider,type=cms
>   portal:service=Interceptor,type=Cms,name=ACL
>   portal:service=ApprovePublish,type=Workflow
>   portal:service=IdentityUIConfigurationService,type=IdentityUI
>   portal:service=IdentityUserManagementService,type=IdentityUI
>   portal.management:service=Management,type=Identity,name=Default
>   portal:service=Interceptor,type=Server,name=User
>   portal:service=Module,type=Mail portal:service=CustomizationManager
>
> > --- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM --- ObjectName: portal:service=Module,type=IdentityServiceController State: FAILED
> >     Reason: org.jboss.portal.identity.IdentityException: Cannot initiate
> >     identity modules:  I Depend On: portal:service=Hibernate
> >     portal:service=IdentityEventManager Depends On Me:
> >     portal:service=AuthorizationProvider,type=cms
> >     portal:service=Interceptor,type=Cms,name=ACL
> >     portal:service=ApprovePublish,type=Workflow
> >     portal:service=IdentityUIConfigurationService,type=IdentityUI
> >     portal:service=IdentityUserManagementService,type=IdentityUI
> >     portal.management:service=Management,type=Identity,name=Default
> >     portal:service=Interceptor,type=Server,name=User
> >     portal:service=Module,type=Mail portal:service=CustomizationManager

Perhaps anyone of you has already encountered such an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element "class" of standardidentity-config.xml must reference the corresponding module, e.g. for User, it has to
reference the implementation of UserModule (and not the implementation of User itself: MyUserImpl!!!), 
and the same for Role, Membership and UserProfile.

So I implemented the interfaces UserModule, RoleModule, etc. But not directly, instead I extended UserModuleService,
RoleModuleService etc. to save some work. The missing properties I mentioned in my last post are no longer necessary then
and can be removed.

The standardidentity-config.xml now looks like this:

```
<module>
    <type>User</type>
    <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>
    <service-name>portal:service=Module,type=User</service-name>
    <class>com.myCompany.MyUserModuleImpl</class>
    <config>
        <option>
            <name>jNDIName</name>
            <value>java:/portal/UserModule</value>
        </option>
    </config>
</module>
<module>
    <type>Role</type>
    <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>
    <service-name>portal:service=Module,type=Role</service-name>
    <class>com.myCompany.MyRoleModuleImpl</class>
    <config>
        <option>
            <name>jNDIName</name>
            <value>java:/portal/RoleModule</value>
        </option>
    </config>
</module>
<module>
    <type>Membership</type>
    <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>
    <service-name>portal:service=Module,type=Membership</service-name>
    <class>com.myCompany.MyMembershipModuleImpl</class>
    <config>
        <option>
            <name>jNDIName</name>
            <value>java:/portal/MembershipModule</value>
        </option>
    </config>
</module>
<module>
    <type>UserProfile</type>
    <implementation>CUSTOM</implementation>
    <service-name>portal:service=Module,type=UserProfile</service-name>
    <class>com.myCompany.MyUserProfileModuleImpl</class>
    <config>
        <option>
            <name>jNDIName</name>
            <value>java:/portal/UserProfileModule</value>
        </option>
    </config>
</module>
```

In order to implement those interfaces I had to add the following dependencies to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.portal.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-common-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```